# high input impedance circuits

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, input-impedance, high-impedance

Working with circuits to get high input impedance. This is to capture signals while introducing as little interference as possible to the preexisting circuit, to load the source as little as possible. One circuit I asked about here before used an instrumentation amplifier design. But there was a problem with input bias and the recommendation I got here would lower the input impedance a lot:
[image: instrumentation amp input stage]

By adding the two Rbias resistors the input impedance would be lowered. This is a partial circuit showing the recommended addition of two 100K resistors. The op amp has a 200 picoamp input bias, so perhaps a larger value could be used?

In another circuit I am working with there is a higher input impedance.
[image: J-fet input stage]

Has anyone had any experience with this circuit configuration? I think it is called a Bastode circuit. It is for a very different application than the in-amp one, but there is the same requirement: the source of the signal must not be affected in any significant way by connection of the circuit. It is really more of a level shifter as well as to isolate the source from interference.

Comment: You might look into using a CA3140T CMOS op-amp with 1.5 T ohm input at 2 pA, or a modern version in a dual package. I have always had to buffer my instrument op-amps with CMOS op-amps for ultra-high impedance.

Comment: That's interesting information. I think the TL072 is good enough for this but it is a shame to 'throw away' it's high impedance with input resistors of 100K. I wondered if 1M would work?

Comment: 1 meg would be ok with a TL072. It is a jfet input.

Comment: muchos gracias amigo